Geometry nodes Instances data export to CSV file
I want to export instances data from spreadsheet, like name, position, rotation, scale to a csv file.
Unfortunately I don't know python, so I can't really solve this question on my own.
I found this thread here, but it only exports data for points, edges or polygons.
Can somebody help to fix it?


got the same problem,...
If u got not so dense geometry and just got 21 instances u could
make instances real and delete the geometry nodes on the instances
create the
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeTAspcBkuk&t=254s&ab_channel=AmanpreetBajwa
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=migdSkt3LIc&t=421s&ab_channel=renderBucket

Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules links to answers are not answers if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.
